# What is cache in GitHub really doing with "git rm -r --cached ."?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a new project to my local and before adding new files or a new branch I called :

`git rm -r --cached .`

This produced a list of files that suddenly became untracked.

1. Is there cache that lives with the repo from the original contributor who checked in the project?
2. How does it determine what files to untrack for a user that has cloned for the first time?

What is that command actually doing?

Comment: You need to start with a basic Git tutorial. That said, I'll mention here that `git rm --cached` removes files from what Git calls the *cache*, the *index*, or the *staging area*, depending on who wrote that particular documentation and what mood they were in. :-) All three are names for the same thing. The index/staging-area/cache is a data structure that sits "between" your current, or `HEAD`, commit, and your work-tree where you do your work. A normal `git rm` removes files from both the index *and* the work-tree; using `git rm --cached` limits this to removing only from the index.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I understand how HEAD is used to stage/stash. I am still unclear though. If I clone for the first time, what was removed? Theoretically  shouldn't it be empty and a message returning `fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files`

Comment: `HEAD` is not used for staging or stashing, `HEAD` is just the current commit. An initial clone ends with a `git checkout` step (checking out something of your choice; your choice usually defaults to the name `master`). This `git checkout` selects which commit is current (usually by selecting a branch name like `master`: the commit is then the tip-most commit of that branch, to which the name points). The `checkout` step populates both the index and the work-tree from that commit. Doing `git rm -r --cached .` would then empty out the index, while leaving the work-tree untouched.

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitGlossary#cache